# How to add postmeta to cart in wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins

It's my first time create a plugin with Wordpress.

my plugin is simple, it's allow me to add addons to the product with images.

My problem is to add a post meta to my cart and update the price.

i cannot paste my class here because is very long.

In the dashboard i click on Add new addon link

1. i set the title.
2. i set the addon items the label name , price, and image.

i render this items in the product page with shortcode this is the function:

```
public function generate_addon_shortcodes()
    {
        $addons = get_posts([
            'post_type' => 'product_addons_hkh',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        ]);

        foreach ($addons as $addon) {
            $addon_items = get_post_meta($addon->ID, 'addon_data', true); // Retrieve addon items meta
            $shortcode_name = 'hkh_addon_' . $addon->ID;

            add_shortcode($shortcode_name, function () use ($addon, $addon_items) {
                ob_start();
                ?>
                <div class="hkh-addon-wrapper">
                    <h2 data-hkh-dropdown-button class="hkh-dropdown-title">
                        <?php echo get_the_title($addon->ID); ?>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="hkh-addon-content" data-hkh-dropdown-content>
                        <?php if (!empty($addon_items)) : ?>
                            <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="selected_addon_data" id="selected_addon_data" value="">'; ?>
                            <?php foreach ($addon_items as $index => $item) : ?>
                                <div class="hkh-col">
                                    <div class="hkh-addon-item">
                                        <?php echo $index;?>
                                        <div class="hkh-note">
                                            <p><?php echo $item['label']; ?></p>
                                            <p>AED<?php echo $item['price']; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="radio" name="addon_radio_<?php echo $addon->ID; ?>" value="<?php echo $index; ?>" id="addon_radio_<?php echo $addon->ID . '_' . $index; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $item['price']; ?>">
                                        <label for="addon_radio_<?php echo $addon->ID . '_' . $index; ?>">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $item['image']; ?>" alt="">
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <p>No addon items found.</p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                return ob_get_clean();
            });
        }
    }
```

so in the product page i have a radio buttons. when the user select any of them i update this hidden input

```
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="selected_addon_data" id="selected_addon_data" value="">'; ?>
```

to the meta post index not the META_ID ***but i am not sure if this good or not***

the record in the database is like this:

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | 39 | addon_data | a:3:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Cong 1";s:5:"price";s:2:"50";s:5:"image";s:93:"http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/WhatsApp-Image-2023-06-15-at-9.44.49-PM.jpeg";}i:1;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Cong 2";s:5:"price";s:2:"50";s:5:"image";s:93:"http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/WhatsApp-Image-2023-06-15-at-9.44.50-PM.jpeg";}i:2;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Cong 3";s:5:"price";s:2:"50";s:5:"image";s:95:"http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/WhatsApp-Image-2023-06-15-at-9.44.50-PM-1.jpeg";}} |

1. so know how to add one of the meta_value that user select in the product page to the cart?
2. how to update the price ?
3. how to add this to the order ?

my class look like this:

```
class ProductAddonsHkh
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Create custom post type.
        add_action('init', [$this, 'create_custom_post_type']);
        add_action('init', [$this, 'generate_addon_shortcodes']);

        // Add & render custom columns to the table.
        add_filter('manage_product_addons_hkh_posts_columns', [$this, 'add_custom_columns']);
        add_action('manage_product_addons_hkh_posts_custom_column', [$this, 'render_custom_columns'], 10, 2);
    }

    // rest code
}
```

I am sorry if i have too much questions

I tried a lot of functions like this:

```
function hkh_add_addon_to_cart() {
    if (isset($_POST['product_id'], $_POST['addon_label'], $_POST['addon_price'])) {
        $product_id = sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_id']);
        $addon_label = sanitize_text_field($_POST['addon_label']);
        $addon_price = sanitize_text_field($_POST['addon_price']);

        // Add the product to the cart with the addon item
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1, 0, array(), array(
            'addon_data' => array(
                'label' => $addon_label,
                'price' => $addon_price,
            )
        ));
    }

    wp_die();
}
```

and no thing happened no thing add it to the cart,

also this function:

```
public function include_addon_price_in_total($total, $cart)
{
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        if (isset($cart_item['selected_addon_data'])) {
            $selected_addon_data = $cart_item['selected_addon_data'];
            $addon_price = $selected_addon_data['price'];

            $total += $addon_price;
        }
    }

    return $total;
}
```

i wanna add the meta_post addon item to the cart with the price and in checkout page, also to the order.

Thanks